# My goal is that all resources of a resourcePool perform an action at a specific time. How do I create this iteration?

Tags: anylogic

I am simulating a hospital stay with anylogic, on multiple levels. Each level has its own staff, represented by different ResourcePool (doctor, nurses, OSS) I created the flowchart of the actions concerning the patient. Now I would like, at a specific time (lunch and dinner), the OSS do tour the patients.
How do I set up that all OSS of a ResourcePool go to the rooms?
I would like to create a very small parallel flowchart, with sieze, moveTo, delay and release.
TNX

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the "Downtime" element to prescribe your resources to do some action, see image below:

[image]

Under the "task type" selection, you can send them to a separate flow chart using a "ResourceTaskStart" element and they will do what you put downstream of that (moveto, delay...). Make sure to finish that with a ResourceTaskEnd block.

PS: The "Downtime" block can easily be triggered via a schedule. Make sure to read the help on that block (and the ResourceTaskStart/End blocks) and study the example models that use those.

Comment: Thank u Benjamin! I tried to do what u suggest me, but it doesn't work, I don't know why. Maybe u can help me, I hope. I can't upload a screenshot, but I try to explain: In downtime the unit type is the agent that have to do the action, the type is maintenance, anche the scedule is a on/off schedule, the other things are like your screeshot. But the resourceTaskStart doesn't work, never.

Comment: Hi Miriana, happy to help, but impossible this way. If you just say "it doesn't work", what should I do? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and open a new, separate issue that is a high-quality question and I am sure we can make progress :)